# Make <i> tag clickable with Angular

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I'm using semantics UI for styling my html5 app. I added a facebook share button as follows:

```
<i ng-click="postToFacebook(competitor.title, competitor.votes)" class="icon facebook"></i>
```

But when I hover over the icon the cursor doesn't change to the hand cursor that usually appears over a clickable link.

I tried wrapping it with anchor tag:

```
<a><i ng-click="postToFacebook(competitor.title, competitor.votes)" class="icon facebook"></i></a>
```

But it just made the icon disappear completely.

Comment: You can control that using CSS: `cursor: pointer;` on that element does the trick.

Comment: @SergiuParaschiv - Thanks! it worked. If you want, post it as an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: Just a side note. `ng-click` will not make an element seem "clickable" unless you define the `cursor: pointer;` style on that element or wrap it in an `<a>` tag. It may be useful to make a `.clickable` CSS class that will set the cursor to a pointer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Following @SergiuParaschiv comment on the question I add a CSS with

```
cursor: pointer;
```

And it worked.

Answer (score 3):

You can wrap your icon in `<a>`, just specify `href` attribute to make it look like a link (place anything that does nothing in `href`):

```
<a href="javascript:"><i ng-click="postToFacebook(competitor.title, competitor.votes)" class="icon facebook"></i></a>
```